# django+gunicorn+nginx gives 404 while serving static files

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx

django+gunicorn+nginx gives 404 while serving static files

I am trying to deploy a Django project using nginx + gunicorn + postgresql. All the configuration is done, my admin panel project static file will serve , but other static files; it returns a 404 error.(iam use run python manage.py collectstatic)

```
my error.log nginx :: "/blogpy/static/home/test.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)" 

Structure: 
blogpy 
  -blogpy 
  -config 
      -nginx
          -nginx.conf
          -docker-compose.yml
          -Dockerfile
  -home 
      -static
          -home
               -test.css(not working)
  - requirements
  -static
  -templates
  -.env
  -docker-compose.yml
  -Dockerfile

setting.py:

   DEBUG = False

   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

nginx configuration:

---- nginx.conf:


user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log     /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    upstream blogpy{
        server blogpy:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass http://blogpy;
        }

        location /static/ {
             alias /blogpy/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get /blogpy/home/static/ files been copied into /blogpy/static/ by collectstatic command, you need to specify STATICFILES_DIRS setting

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

```
STATICFILES_DIRS  = [
    BASE_DIR / 'home' / 'static',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to serve static files directly from `nginx`.

Add the following to your nginx site config.

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/static/directory/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
In ---- nginx.conf:

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex off;
    alias /home/ubuntu/blogpy/static/; #add full path of static file directry
}
```